# Trouble with JS form elements

Tags: php, javascript

I've built a form with a checkbox and a few text fields and I've set it up so that a user can add additional occurrences of this set of elements.  I've done this by creating a div containing these elements with display set to 'none.'  Javascript then clones and displays this div as needed (once if no $_POST data; once for user click; x times if there is $_POST data).  The Javascript also labels the elements uniquely and sequentially - I've set it up to read in to a serialized array for eventual MySQL insertion - "occurrence[integer][name]".

So far, so good.  Everything behaves as it should and $_POST output is exactly what I need for MySQL.

My trouble is coming in trying to display the $_POST data within the form elements.  In the code below, I've got a JS variable set to PHP $_POST data - which actually works, so long as I use static code without any variables.  In other words,

```
newField[i].value ='<?php echo $_POST[occurrence][1][start_date]; ?>';
```

does indeed display that value (albeit in every field).
And obviously

```
newField[i].value ='['+counter+']['+theName+']';
```

correctly displays that field's counter and name.  But when I try to combine like so is when I get nothing

```
newField[i].value ='<?php echo $_POST[occurrence]['+counter+']['+theName+']; ?>';
```

Here's my full code:

```
<?php
        $occ_count = count($_POST['occurrence']);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var counter = 0;
    function moreFields() { // this function clones the div containing the elements and allows it to display
        counter++;
        var newFields = document.getElementById('readroot').cloneNode(true);
        newFields.id = '';
        newFields.style.display = 'block';
        var newField = newFields.childNodes;
        for (var i=0;i<newField.length;i++) {
            var theName = newField[i].name
            if (theName) {
                newField[i].name = 'occurrence['+counter+']['+theName+']';
            }
            newField[i].value ='<?php echo $_POST[occurrence]['+counter+']['+theName+']; ?>';
        }
        var insertHere = document.getElementById('writeroot');
        insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields,insertHere);
    }
    function addLoadEvent(func) { // this function allows multiple functions to be called on page load
        var oldonload = window.onload;
        if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
            window.onload = func;
        } else {
            window.onload = function() {
                if (oldonload) {
                    oldonload();
                }
                func();
            }
        }
    }

    // this bit determines how many times the moreFields function should be called, based on $_POST data
    var occ_count = "<?php echo $occ_count; ?>";
    if(occ_count == 0) {window.onload = moreFields;}
    else if(occ_count >= 1) {
        for (var n=0;n<occ_count;n++) {
            addLoadEvent(moreFields);
        }
    }
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>JS test2</h2>

        <div id="readroot" style="display: none">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<label for="all_day">All Day</label>&nbsp;
            <input type="checkbox" name="all_day"
             onClick="allday(this, this.form)"/>

            &nbsp;&nbsp;<label for="start_date">From:</label>&nbsp;
            <input type="text" name="start_date"
            value="" size="15" />

            &nbsp;&nbsp;<label for="start_time"></label>&nbsp;
            <input type="text" name="start_time"
            value="" size="15" />

            &nbsp;&nbsp;<label for="end_date">To:</label>&nbsp;
            <input type="text" name="end_date"
            value="" size="15" />

            &nbsp;&nbsp;<label for="end_time"></label>&nbsp;
            <input type="text" name="end_time"
            value="" size="15" />

            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:;" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);">Delete</a>

            <br /><br />
            <hr style="border: 0;color: #ddd;background-color: #ddd;height: 1px;">

        </div> <!--readroot-->

        <form method="post" >
            <span id="writeroot"></span>
            <p id="addnew"><a href="javascript:moreFields()">Add New</a></p>

            <input type="submit" value="Send form" />
        </form>

<hr>

<?php if($_POST) : ?>
<?php // this is purely for troubleshooting
    echo 'count: '.count($_POST['occurrence']).'<br />';
    foreach ( $_POST as $varname => $postitem ) {
        echo 'name: '.$varname.' value: ';
        print_r($postitem);
        echo '<br />';
    }
?>
<?php endif; ?>
    </body>
```

I can't figure out if this is just a syntax issue or just structurally impossible.  I know JS is supposed to load after PHP but yet I can get that JS variable to produce php $_POST data so there's something going on.  Obviously, I'm confused.  But I'm also open to any other (even completely different) ideas on how to accomplish what I need.

Thanks for any thoughts, ideas or suggestions!

Comment: I do not know php well enough, but it appears you are mixing server side php and client side JavaScript `newField[i].value ='<?php echo $_POST[occurrence]['+counter+']['+theName+']; ?>';`  `counter` and `theName` will not evaluate your echo statement correctly since they are not processed on the server but the client.

Comment: Mark is right, you can't access a PHP variable in this way. If you are using PHP5 you can use something like js_post ='<?php echo json_encode($_POST); ?>' and access the post data as a js object. Be careful though, as this method will make your post data much easier to access by nasties through js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Mark states, you're trying to concatenate server-side PHP with client-side Javascript - this simply isn't going to work. Everything within your `<?php` and `?>` tags will be evaluated before the page is ever sent to the client - so the actual PHP code will be this:

```
echo $_POST['occurrence']['+counter+']['+theName+'];
```

I'd guess this actually tries to look up keys called `'+counter+'` and ``'+theName+' in your PHP array, and of course these don't exist.

There are a couple of ways to do this right - my guess is that the easiest would be to dump the PHP into a javascript variable:

```
var postOccurrence = <?php echo json_encode($_POST['occurrence']); ?>;
```

Then update your code in the Javascript loop to:

```
newField[i].value = postOccurrence[counter][theName];
```

The other easy option would be to do the loop in PHP, rather than Javascript, and have it output static Javascript code for fields from 0 to n.

Comment: Updated, thanks. Sloppy cut-and-paste from the OP without checking syntax.

Comment: @nrabinowitz - Thanks for the help - I think json_decode is what I need.  But I'm having trouble accessing the values in the var postOccurrence. First, I modified var creation to add echo and single quotes: postOccurrence = '<?php echo json_encode($_POST['occurrence']); ?>'; otherwise it wouldn't load. If I set the newField var to just postOccurrence, I can see all the values but neither [counter][theName] or [1]['start_date'] or [1].start_date will pull them out.  What am I missing? thanks!

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to work locally. Can you point me to your working copy or cut and paste what the json_encode line is spitting out?

Comment: @nrabinowitz - Thank for looking.  Here is what it spits out, with one or two occurrences, respectively (the 'ddd' and 'mmm' are my test entries): {"1":{"start_date":"ddd","start_time":"null","end_date":"null","end_time":"null"}}

{"1":{"start_date":"ddd","start_time":"null","end_date":"null","end_time":"null"},"2":{"start_date":"mmm","start_time":"null","end_date":"null","end_time":"null"}}
Here is a link: http://stacefelder.com/jstest2.php  I'll try to leave it alone for awhile so you can take a look.  Thanks again.

Comment: I see. The issue here is that json_encode is producing an object with string keys, not an array with integer keys, but you're trying to reference this with integers. Try this: newField[i].value = postOccurrence[counter.toString()][theName];

Comment: @nrabinowitz - Still no love.  Trying counter.toString()] , parseInt(counter) also replacing the counter var with single integer, just for testing.  Reading around, it seems this sort of issue has come up before but haven't found a clear answer.  Seems like it might be better to deal with this further upstream, maybe just before or after the json decode.  Or is there a better way to get the $_POST var into JS?

Comment: @nrabinowitz - In an effort to try to convert those string keys in to integer keys, I also tried this - var postOccurrence = '<?php echo preg_replace( "/\"(\d+)\"/", '$1', json_encode($_POST['occurrence'])); ?>'; - which does indeed remove the double-quotes on the numbers - {1:{"start_date":"ddd","start_time":"null","end_date":"null","end_time":"null"}} - but I still can't get those values out.

Comment: @Stace - both parseInt(counter) and replacing the counter with an integer go in the wrong direction (you'd end up with an integer, not a string, and you need a string). I wouldn't go with the regex - it's more complication than you need. When I try this: po = {"1":{"start_date":"ddd","start_time":"null","end_date":"null","end_time":"null"}}; po["1"]["start_date"]; -- it works fine, returning "ddd". If this doesn't work for you, there's another problem somewhere else in your code.

Comment: @nrabinowitz - Indeed, your example works,  I even replaced your po value with a cut/paste from postOccurrence output with same success.  But var postOccurrence = '<?php echo json_encode($_POST['occurrence']); ?>'; does not, even though it APPEARS to produce the same output as the po var.  Obviously, I'm missing something - maybe some sort of escaping thing within the json_encode function that I can't see when viewing as an alert box? Thanks for sticking with me on this - it really helps.

Comment: You shouldn't have quotes around the json_encode output - this is converting the output to a string, rather than a javascript object. Remove the quotes and it'll probably work.

Comment: @nrabinowitz - Gotcha - works like a charm!  I can now display the proper value in the intended field.  But there's a secondary issue: this only works when there is a value set for the params I'm calling.  In other words, when I call postOccurrence[1]['start_date'] and the Javascript object has that defined, it all works.  But if the object doesn't have that value, my script breaks.  I've tried to check for the value as a condition but then the test chokes the script.  Can you suggest a method for checking this?  Thanks very much.

Comment: @Stace - You have to check each "level" of an object one by one: if (postOccurrence && postOccurrence[counter]) newField[i].value = ...etc. If I've answered your original question, can you mark my answer as accepted?

Comment: @nrabinowitz - Again, you've nailed it for me.  Thank you very much for all of your help and patience.  It all makes sense in hindsight; unfortunately I don't have enough skill to have good foresight.  I will mark this as answered and really appreciate all you've done.